# Protractor proper way to use browser.wait to control flow of tests

Tags: protractor

I have written a few functions for browser.wait. My problem is when I run my tests, they inconsistently pass due to protractor running too fast. To combat this, I was using browser.sleep. This works, but is not efficient. If I am on a slow connection for example, these browser.sleep statements can become unreliable. So I have started to use browser.wait. Here is an example of a wait function that I use.

```
EC = Expected Conditions;
myForm = element(by.id('myForm');
button1 = element(by.id('btn1');
waitForBtn = this.EC.elementToBeClickable(button1)
formIsVisible = this.EC.visibilityOf(myForm)

//Test
it(should click the button and bring up the form), () => {
    browser.wait(page.waitForBtn, 3000);
    page.button1.click()
    browser.wait(page.formIsVisible, 3000);
    expect(page.getMyForm().isDisplayed).toBeTruthy();
```

This test would work in isoluation, but when combinded with other tests, sometimes a test will fail and return an error`"element" is not clickable at point...`. Even with these wait functions, I will receive this error. It always seems to be for when an element is being clicked.

My question is this: **When running multiple tests, what is the best way for protractor to wait so that protractor does not execute the test too fast and miss the element?**  Thank you.
EDIT:
Here is the solution.

Helper function for clicking elements.

```
 async function sendClick(el: ElementFinder): Promise<void> {
    try {

      let result = await forCondition(function() { return el.isDisplayed() });
      if(!result || !await el.isEnabled()) {
        throw new Error('element disabled');
      }

      await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', el.getWebElement());
    } catch(error) {
      console.warn('element:', el.locator().toString(), 'is not clickable', error.message);
    }
  }

export async function forCondition(condition: () => any | PromiseLike<boolean>, timeout = 20000): Promise<boolean> {
try {
  return await browser.wait(condition, timeout);
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Condition: false');
  return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell you the best way, but this is one way :)

Usually, errors like `element" is not clickable at point...` are caused when the element is overlapped by another element OR if it has not finished rendering yet.

1) For preventing `element is not clickable` error, you should use `javascript` for clicking. One disadvantage is that elements always get clicked. Means you have to check manually if the element is clickable and should only click if it is.
A 'proper' click function could look as follows:

```
async function sendClick(el: ElementFinder): Promise<void> {
  try {

    // forCondition() is a custom function and listed below..
    let result = await forCondition(function() { return el.isDisplayed() });
    if(!result || !await el.isEnabled()) {
      throw new Error('element disabled');
    }

    // click via javascript
    await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', el.getWebElement());
  } catch(error) {
    console.warn('element:', el.locator().toString(), 'is not clickable', error.message);
  }
}
```

Above function waits for the element to be displayed and clicks it if it's enabled.

Here is the helper function::

`forCondition()` which waits for a condition to fullfill. You cann add more logic to `forCondition()` for making sure the page is loaded (let's say until spinner disappear or something similar.)

```
export async function forCondition(condition: () => boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>, timeout = 20000): Promise<boolean> {
  try {
    // add function which waits until page is loaded here..
    return await browser.wait(condition, timeout);
  } catch (err) {
    logger.silly('Condition: false');
    return false;
  }
}
```

In tests it would look as follows:

```
it('should click element', async function() {
  let button = element(by.id('myButton');

  // it's waited until button appears and clicks it if possible.
  await sendClick(button);
});
```

If you always use these helper functions you can easily add checks for waiting for the page to be loaded or other custom logic.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. I am currently working in angular 6. When writing the function for sendClick, I receive a typescript error on the line `let result = await forCOndition(function(){el.isDisplayed()}`; The error states that  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean | PromiseLike<boolean>'

Comment: Ah yes. We usually work with arrow functions. With them you do not need to write return. So this is the function you want  `let result = await forCOndition(function(){return el.isDisplayed()});`

And with arrow funcitons it would look as follows:
`let result = await forCondition(() => el.isDisplayed());`
I adjusted the asnwer,

Comment: Thank you once again. I still having trouble with the promises. I receive a simular error now saying  `Type 'Promise<boolean>' is not assignable to type PromiseLike<boolean>.` I updated my question will the full error.

Comment: Ok please try to change the typing of `forCondition()` as follows::
`export async function forCondition(condition: () => boolean | PromiseLike<boolean> | Promise<boolean>, timeout = 20000): Promise<boolean> {
// ... 
}`

I added the type `Promise<boolean>`. If that does not work try to use the function without typing. If it works without them, you have to figure out correct types:) For me it works like that..

Comment: With your advice, I removed the type boolean from the Promise in the forCondinition function. It would look like this: `export async function forCondition(condition: () => any | PromiseLike<boolean>...` Thank you! Now my tests are a million times more efficient.

Comment: Well I would not advice to set an `any` type since everytime you pass something in which does not resolve to a boolean value, the function will just time out. So please try to find the correct type >)

Comment: Hmmmm, I am just a little confused on the error. It is saying that promise<boolean> cannot be assigned to PromiseLike<boolean>. To my understanding they are the same thing?

Comment: If I understood `PromiseLike` correctly or in general all `like` types, It's usually just a minified interface of the real interface. Means, `PromiseLike` does most likely have fewer properties than `Promise`. The Problem is, they are still different interfaces. So You most likely have to decide which one to use in your project.